# How did Conrad come back to life after the gunshot in "The Game"?

Tags: analysis, plot-explanation, the-game

In [The Game](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119174/),

> At the end of the movie Conrad was shot by his own brother Nicholas Van Orton. But Conrad came back to life at the very end of the movie.
>
>  How it this possible? Because, Nicholas Van Orton took the gun from his house, which was hidden inside the book named **To Kill a Mocking Bird**.
>
>  And also, I think it's a real gun. Because, the conversation between Christine and Nicholas Van Orton clearly elaborates **it was a real gun**.

Here are the conversation between Christine and Nicholas Van Orton,

> Where'd you get that? What?
>
> That gun, that's not an automatic--
>
> What the fuck are you talking about?
>
> We all had an automatic. Where did you get the gun?
>
> This is my gun.
>
> But we've searched the house
>
> Well, I guess you missed this, didn't you?
>
> Listen, we got a real Goddamn gun up here
>
> ................
>
> Nicholas, Nicholas, listen
> Damn it, he's got a real gun with real goddamned bullets.

I couldn't understand how it's possible to come back to life after being shot by a real gun. Did i miss something in the movie?
Any help will be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The gun was switched, but they pretended not to have known about it. This was one last psych out.

Comment: Thanks James...But,do you have any source for what you're saying,I don't think the gun was switched, because Christine was yelling on Nicholas as it wasn't automatic and it loaded with bullets.Perhaps, the gun was hid perfectly in a book,so it wouldn't be easy for CRS to find out and be switched.

Comment: She's an actress. She was acting, according to the script set up by CRS. She fooled him, and she fooled you. Think about it - does any other explanation make sense?

Comment: I think you can also ascertain her acting when she says "where'd you get the gun" .... "but we've searched the house". Its highly unlikely they emptied the whole house except for a jar full of money and a gun. They were put there on purpose for the last setup. The game is a brilliant movie.

Comment: @VijinPaulraj You may not like James's answer, but it's true. By the end, Nicholas knew it was all a setup so they played on that fact, pretending that the weapon he had was real, when in fact the whole purpose of THE GAME was to push him into jumping off the roof. It's an excellent script.

Comment: @VijinPaulraj You should accept this answer, it's pretty correct. The only alternative would be Christine's radio message to cause Conrad to put on a bulletproof vest. But even then there was no way of telling Nicholas wouldn't hit Conrad's head. CRS was most likely video surveying him picking up the gun, so they would have intervened one way or another if they _really_ wouldn't have found these real bullets.

Comment: What I don’t understand: shouldn’t people have been dodging the failing shards of glass from the ceiling Conrad goes through when he tries to commit suicide before landing on the air balloon? Instead they’re all just dressed up in their best, applauding him, like it’s all ok.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan that should be a new question. But my guess would be that they knew he was going to do this so they replaced the pane of glass with something that doesn’t shard, like https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar_glass

Comment: @MissouriSpartan I suggest you to listen to the David Fincher audio commentaries (https://youtu.be/Qzwd7jOm1gM?t=6917). It is said that the scene that was shot looks spectacular and utterly implausible.